# How to create an API with severals DB connections

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to create an API in .NET to connect and verify some data in several database engines (MySQl, PostgreSQL, SQL Server).
I can make one connection, but I don't understand how to make more than one.

Here's my code:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region MSSqlServer
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLSRV");
    services
            .AddDbContext<SQLSRVDBContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services
            .AddTransient<IService, Service>();
    #endregion

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLSRV": "Server=localhost;Database= dbName;User Id=dbUser;Password=dbPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    },
```

Interface

```
namespace VerificaUsuarios.Interfaces
{
    public interface IService
    {
        bool GetUsuarioSG(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
namespace VerificaUsuarios.Services
{
    using VerificaUsuarios.Interfaces;
    using VerificaUsuarios.Models;
    using VerificaUsuarios.Persistence;
    using System.Linq;
    using global::ADWS;

    public class Service : IService
    {
        private readonly SQLSRVDBContext _sQLSRVDBContext;

        public Service(SQLSRVDBContext sQLSRVDBContext)
        {
            _sQLSRVDBContext = sQLSRVDBContext;
        }
        
        public bool GetUsuarioSG(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = new UsuariosSG();

            var activeDirectory = new AD_WSClient();

            try
            {
                bool isUsuario = activeDirectory.LoginAsync(userName, password).Result;
                
                if(isUsuario)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = _sQLSRVDBContext
                                                .Usuarios
                                                .Where(u => u.UsrLogin.Trim() == userName.Trim())
                                                .First();
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
             
            }
            catch(System.Exception excep)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the db context

```
namespace VerificaUsuarios.Persistence
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using VerificaUsuarios.Models;
    public partial class SQLSRVDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public SQLSRVDBContext()
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<UsuariosSG>  Usuarios{ get; set; }

        public SQLSRVDBContext(DbContextOptions<SQLSRVDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core and Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157196/ef-core-and-multiple-databases)

Comment: Are you dead set on performing this exclusively in code? If not, perhaps consider using Linked Servers.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4570/access-mysql-data-from-sql-server-via-a-linked-server/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/

Then you build views and stored procedures to query all the data sources in one go with one DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example of connection to different motors with validation against active directory

1) install the different EF Core Database Providers in VS

Entity Framework Core uses a provider model to access many different databases. EF Core includes providers as NuGet packages which you need to install.

The following lists database providers and NuGet packages for EF Core (NuGet package).

```
SQL Server  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
MySQL   MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
PostgreSQL  Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

2)Perform the Scaffold-DbContext to the bd and tables that you want to use in the different engines.
PostgreSQL

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models -Table MyTablePSQL
```

MySql

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=myserver;port=3306;user=myuser;password=mypass;database=mydb" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -f -Table MyTableMySQL
```

SqlServer

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Table MyTableSQL
```

3)add the different connection string in the appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLSRV": "Server=myserver;Database= mydb;User Id=myuser;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MySql": "server=myserver;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;port=3306;database=mydb;",
    "PSQL": "Host=myserver;Database=mydb;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword"
    },
```

4) modify the DbContext generated by the Scaffold-DbContext

SQLSRVDBContext

```
namespace MyProject.Persistence
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using MyProject.Models;
    public partial class SQLSRVDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public SQLSRVDBContext()
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<MyTableSQL>  Users{ get; set; }

        public SQLSRVDBContext(DbContextOptions<SQLSRVDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
    }
}
```

MySQLDBContext

```
namespace MyProject.Persistence
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using MyProject.Models;
    public partial class MySQLDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MySQLDBContext()
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<MyTableMySQL> Users { get; set; }

        public MySQLDBContext(DbContextOptions<MySQLDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

    }
}
```

PostgreSQL

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public partial class PostgreSQLDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public PostgreSQLDBContext()
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<MyTablePSQL> Users { get; set; }

        public PostgreSQLDBContext(DbContextOptions<PostgreSQLDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

5)create Interfaces

SQLSRV

```
namespace MyProject.Interfaces
{
    public interface IService
    {
        bool GetUserSQLSRV(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

MySQL

```
namespace MyProject.Interfaces
{
    public interface IServiceMySQL
    {
        bool GetUserMySQL(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

PostgreSQL

```
namespace MyProject.Interfaces
{
    public interface IServicePSQL
    {
        bool GetUserPSQL(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

6)create the Services

SQLSRV(SQLSRVDBContext)

```
namespace MyProject.Services
{
    using MyProject.Interfaces;
    using MyProject.Models;
    using MyProject.Persistence;
    using System.Linq;
    using global::ADWS;

    public class Service : IService
    {
        private readonly SQLSRVDBContext _sQLSRVDBContext;

        public Service(SQLSRVDBContext sQLSRVDBContext)
        {
            _sQLSRVDBContext = sQLSRVDBContext;
        }

        public bool GetUserSQLSRV(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = new MyTableSQL();

            var activeDirectory = new AD_WSClient();

            try
            {
                bool isUser = activeDirectory.LoginAsync(userName, password).Result;

                if(isUser)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = _sQLSRVDBContext
                                                    .Users
                                                    .Where(u => u.UsrLogin.Trim() == userName.Trim())
                                                    .First();
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch(System.Exception excep)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MySQL(MySQLDBContext)

```
namespace MyProject.Services
{
    using MyProject.Interfaces;
    using MyProject.Models;
    using MyProject.Persistence;
    using System.Linq;
    using global::ADWS;

    public class ServiceMySQL : IServiceMySQL
    {
        private readonly MySQLDBContext _mySQLDBContext;

        public ServiceMySQL(MySQLDBContext mySQLDBContext)
        {
            _mySQLDBContext = mySQLDBContext;
        }

        public bool GetUserMySQL(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = new MyTableMySQL();

            var activeDirectory = new AD_WSClient();

            try
            {
                bool isUser = activeDirectory.LoginAsync(userName, password).Result;

                if(isUser)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = _mySQLDBContext
                                                .Users
                                                .Where(u => u.UsrLogin.Trim() == userName.Trim())
                                                .First();
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch(System.Exception excep)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PostgreSQL(PostgreSQLDBContext)

```
namespace MyProject.Services
{
    using MyProject.Interfaces;
    using MyProject.Models;
    using MyProject.Persistence;
    using System.Linq;
    using global::ADWS;

    public class ServicePSQL : IServicePSQL
    {
        private readonly PostgreSQLDBContext _postgreSQLDBContext;

        public ServicePSQL(PostgreSQLDBContext postgreSQLDBContext)
        {
            _postgreSQLDBContext = postgreSQLDBContext;
        }

        public bool GetUserPSQL(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = new MyTablePSQL();

            var activeDirectory = new AD_WSClient();

            try
            {
                bool isUser = activeDirectory.LoginAsync(userName, password).Result;

                if(isUser)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = _postgreSQLDBContext
                                                    .Users
                                                    .Where(u => u.UsrLogin.Trim() == userName.Trim())
                                                    .First();
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch(System.Exception excep)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

7) configure the different services in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region SQLSRV
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLSRV");
    services
            .AddDbContext<SQLSRVDBContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services
            .AddTransient<IService, Service>();

    #endregion

    #region MySql
    var connectionMySql = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQL");
    services
            .AddDbContext<MySQLDBContext>
            (options => options.UseMySQL(connectionMySql));
    services
            .AddTransient<IServiceMySQL, ServiceMySQL>();
    #endregion

    #region PostgreSQL
    var connectionPSQL = Configuration.GetConnectionString("PSQL");
    services
            .AddDbContext<PostgreSQLDBContext>
            (options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionPSQL));
    services.AddTransient<IServicePSQL, ServicePSQL>();

    #endregion

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

8)creation of the different Controller

SQLSRV

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using MyProject.Interfaces;

    [Route("api/GET/[controller]")]
    public class UserSQLSRVController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IService _userSQLSRVService;

        public UserSQLSRVController(IService userSQLSRVService)
        {
            _userSQLSRVService = userSQLSRVService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUserSQLSRV(string userName, string password)
        {
            return Ok(
                _userSQLSRVService.GetUserSQLSRV(userName, password));
        }
    }
}
```

MySQL

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using MyProject.Interfaces;

    [Route("api/GET/[controller]")]
    public class UserMySqlController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IServiceMySQL _userMySqlService;

        public UserMySqlController(IServiceMySQL userMySqlService)
        {
            _userMySqlService = userMySqlService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUserMySQL(string userName, string password)
        {
            return Ok(
                _userMySqlService.GetUserMySQL(userName, password));
        }
    }
}
```

PSQL

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using MyProject.Interfaces;

    [Route("api/GET/[controller]")]
    public class UserPSQLController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IServicePSQL _userPSQLService;

        public UserPSQLController(IServicePSQL userPSQLService)
        {
            _userPSQLService = userPSQLService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUserPSQL(string userName, string password)
        {
            return Ok(
                _userPSQLService.GetUserPSQL(userName, password));
        }
    }
}
```